# In what sense is $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{x}{x^2+1} \, dx = \pi i$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value

Suppose we want to give a meaning to the divergent integral
$$I = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{x}{x^2+1} \, dx,$$
perhaps in the sense of distributions or something (similarly to how $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } x e^{i k x} dx$ can be given meaning as the derivative of the delta function).

Because the integrand is odd, it seems sensible to say $I = 0$.
But for all $a$ for which the integral converges,
$$I = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{x^{a-1}}{x^2+1} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \pi  \left( 1 -(-1)^a\right) \csc \left(\frac{\pi  a}{2}\right).$$

Analytically continuing this to $a = 2$ gives $I = \pi i$.
Added: $$\lim \limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{x \, e^{i \epsilon x}}{x^2+1}dx = \pi i.$$ I cannot justify switching integral and limit...

Is there a unique and 'useful' way to give a meaning to $I$ in some mathematically rigorous sense?

Comment: I think there must be a mistake somewhere, you cannot add a collection of Real-valued terms and have them add up to a non-Real complex value $\pi i$

Comment: @PassingBy I suppose the divergent integral cannot be interpreted as adding up a collection of real-valued terms anymore.

Comment: But I think if the integral converges, it is the (limit of the Riemann) sum of Real-valued terms, and so it must be Real-valued.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

By the $\Gamma$ reflection formula it follows that:
$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{x^2+1}\,dx = \pi\sin\frac{\pi a}{2}$$
for any $a$ in the strip $0<\Re(a)<2$, so the analytic continuation gives $I(2)=0$, as expected.

Comment: Can you explain how you obtained this formula? I know how to derive it when integrating over $(0,\infty)$. But now we integrate over the negative reals as well.

Comment: I assumed that for negative values of $x$, $x^{a-1}$ is defined as $\exp\left((a-1)\log x\right)=\exp\left((a-1)\left(\pi i+\log(-x)\right)\right).$

Comment: I am probably mistaken here, but doesn't this give $\frac 1 2 \left[ \exp((a-1)\pi i) + 1 \right] \csc(\pi a /2)$ for the value of the integral? Or where does the factor with $\exp((a-1)\pi i)$ go?

Answer (score 0):

More playing around.

If any of the steps
I do here are valid,
please tell me 
so I can remove them.

$I = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{x}{x^2+1} \, dx,$

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{a(x-i)+b(x+i)}{(x+i)(x-i)}
&=\frac{(a+b)x+(b-a)i}{(x+i)(x-i)}\\
&=\frac{x}{(x+i)(x-i)} \text{ if } (b-a)=0, b+a=1 \text{, or } a=1/2, b=1/2\\
so\ \frac{x}{x^2+1}&=\frac{1/2}{x+i}+\frac{1/2}{x-i}\\
\end{array}
$

Now watch closely.

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{x+i} \, dx
&=\mid_{-\infty }^{\infty } \ln(x+i)\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}(\ln(x+i)-\ln(-x-i))\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln\frac{x+i}{-x-i}\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln\frac{1+i/x}{-1-i/x}\\
&= \ln(-1)\\
&=\pi i
\end{array}
$

Similarly,
$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{x-i} \, dx
=\pi i
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{x}{x^2+1} \, dx
&=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \left(\frac{1/2}{x+i}+\frac{1/2}{x-i}\right) \, dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1/2}{x+i}\, dx+\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{1/2}{x-i}\, dx\\
&= \frac{\pi i}{2}+\frac{\pi i}{2}\\
&=\pi i
\end{array}
$

I'll bet Euler would agree.

Comment: "Similarly, $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{x+i} \, dx
=\pi i$." I think you meant $\frac1{x-i}$?

Comment: Right. Thanks. A copy-and-paste error. Fixed. Wouldn't happen in Microsoft Word.

Comment: By the way: the fifth equality sign after "Now watch closely" is probably not valid. Something something branch cuts something. (I don't know that much about complex numbers, don't judge.)

Comment: Euler knew that there was more than one $\ln(-1)$. (He was the one who discovered it!)

Comment: I guess as long as you take complementary branch cuts for the two integrals, it works out. I was purposely not worrying, since complex analysis is one of my many areas of inexpertise.

Comment: @martycohen: if you assumed $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x+i}=\pi i$, then $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x-i}$ should be just the conjugate, i.e. $\color{red}{-}\pi i$.

Comment: The rule $\ln(zw)=\ln z + \ln w$ isn't necessarily valid for complex numbers; you have to be very careful with branch cuts (and define what you mean by "ln" to begin with). (And also $\ln(-x-i)$ should be $\ln(-x+i)$.)

Comment: As I said, I was just playing around and not worrying too much how rigorous or even valid my manipulations were. Just having fun.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Indeed in this way the right result 0 comes out.